# Runtime error using Python Library Keops using CUDA in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, pytorch

I am trying to run samples from the Python library: [GeomLoss](https://www.kernel-operations.io/geomloss/_auto_examples/index.html), which depends on CUDA, Pytorch and [Keops](https://www.kernel-operations.io/keops/index.html) in Ubuntu 18.04.3. I downloaded Python3.7 using Anaconda, and I am using CUDA 10.1. The gcc version is 7.4.0.

When I run samples from GeomLoss, the error message said:

> RuntimeError: [KeOps] This KeOps shared object has been compiled
>   without cuda support: try to set tagHostDevice to 0 or recompile the
>   formula with a working version of cuda.

I cannot change tagHostDevice to 0 since this will disable GPU calculation according to their documentation. I checked CUDA and Pytorch installation and they was no error. 
But when I tried to run the installation checking code from KeOps:

```
import torch
import pykeops.torch as pktorch

x = torch.arange(1, 10, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 3)
y = torch.arange(3, 9, dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 3)

my_conv = pktorch.Genred('SqNorm2(x-y)', ['x = Vi(3)', 'y = Vj(3)'])
print(my_conv(x, y))
```

I received error message:

> error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported! ^~~~~ CMake Error at
>   keopslibKeOpstorch91c92bd508_generated_link_autodiff.cu.o.Release.cmake:219

I checked CUDA documentation, for Ubuntu 18.04.3, the native linux distribution support should be gcc-7.3.0. for x86_64. I used `gcc --version` to check default gcc in system and it is using gcc-7.4.0. I am not sure if this is the problem with using KeOps with CUDA and GPU. Also, I believe KeOps will not support gcc versions before 7. So I am really confused about what should I do to fix the problem right now.

I am wondering if anyone has experienced similar problems with GeomLoss and KeOps or other libraries. I am indeed grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps and it worked for me:

First, by checking the dependencies in this [link](http://www.kernel-operations.io/keops/python/installation.html) I noticed that `nvcc` compiler is not installed. By going to [Nvidia Toolkit Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) I did the following steps:

```sh
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.2.2/local_installers/cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run
sudo sh cuda_11.2.2_460.32.03_linux.run
```

Then I realized that `nvcc` command not working, so I did add them to the path using:

```sh
nano ~/.bashrc

# Add the following two lines: 
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"
```

In general, it is important to see the logs of `PyKeops` to check the process. So, you can always change the `verbose` and `debug` mode and see the details to check out what failed:

```py
# Testing PyKeops installation
import pykeops

# Changing verbose and mode
pykeops.verbose = True
pykeops.build_type = 'Debug'

# Clean up the already compiled files
pykeops.clean_pykeops()

# Test Numpy integration
pykeops.test_numpy_bindings()
```

Comment: Before I forget, if your `cmake` is not the version needed by `pykeops`, reinstall it using this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/829310/how-to-upgrade-cmake-in-ubuntu